# Android: Parse 2 jsonArray

Tags: android, json

How i can parse 2 json Array in Android?
Plz see the following code;

```
    {
"detail": [
    {
        "price": 51,
        "numsc": 2,
        "name": "this app is about animals",
        "sc1": "printed-dress.jpg",
        "sc2": "printed-dress2.jpg"
    }
],
"colors": [
    {
        "color": "#5D9CEC",
        "name": "blue"
    },
    {
        "color": "#FCCACD",
        "name": "pink"
    }
]
```

}

can you help me plz??

Comment: here is one object and one array in a object, what the problem to parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject object  = new JSONObject(your-string);

    JSONArray details=object.getJSONArray("details");
for(int j=0;j<details.length();j++){
       JSONObject detail= details.getJSONObject(i);
    String price = detail.getString("price");
    ....
    }
    JSONArray colors = object.getJSONArray("colors");

    for(int i=0;i<colors.length();i++){
       JSONObject obj= colors.getJSONObject(i);
       // parse your json here
    String color = obj.getString("color")

    }
```

Comment: "detail" is a JSONArray not a JSONObject.

Comment: Thank you! it's Work Fine.

Answer (score 0):

See following code:

```
private void decodeJSON()
    {
        String JSONString = "you json String";
        try
        {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSONString);
            JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("detail");
            JSONObject detail = arr.getJSONObject(0);
            int price = detail.getInt("price"); // do same thing to get other values


            arr = obj.getJSONArray("colors");
            JSONObject color = arr.getJSONObject(0);
            String colorValue = color.getString("color");
            String name = color.getString("name");

            // do same thing for next object in array.
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```