# How to catch the JSON response when response have two or more arrays in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

This is my `JSON` data format

```
[{"member":[{"id":"1","name":"A V S Murthy (Sanjeev)","mobile1":"9845072215","mail_id":"alampalli.murthy@gmail.com","bg":"O +Ve"},{"id":"67","name":"Sundaramurthy N C","mobile1":"9845026300\t","mail_id":"ncsmurthy1943@gmail.com","bg":"O +Ve"}]},{"anne":[{"id":"1","name":"A V S Murthy (Sanjeev)","mobile1":"9845072215","mail_id":"alampalli.murthy@gmail.com","bg":"O +Ve","anne_name":"Shoba A Murthy","anne_mobile":"","anne_email":""}]},{"annets":[]}]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31532008/8648705

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First visit to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and create your model classes. (or create manually)
Than use to https://github.com/google/gson library for parsing